# Button stays yellow on button click while nothing happens

Tags: android, button, onclick, imageview

I have a button and imageview in my layout. When button is clicked imageview supposed to become visible.I.e. the algorithm is:
1) click button
2) imageview becomes visible
3) other actions. 
 However it doesn't work always like that. Sometimes on button click the button stays yellow and does nothing, no exceptions thrown either. When I tap anywhere on the screen it continues on step 3 and button becomes deselected again.
 What might be the reason of such an odd behaviour?

Edit: Here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/water_room_layout" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/water_room_flipper"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <include layout="@layout/water_room_wall1" android:id="@+id/first" />
        <include layout="@layout/water_room_wall2" android:id="@+id/second" />
        <include layout="@layout/water_room_wall3" android:id="@+id/third" />
        <include layout="@layout/water_room_wall4" android:id="@+id/fourth" />
    </ViewFlipper>

     <com.example.room.CustomView
        android:id="@+id/customView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

This is water_room_wall1.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/wall1Layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/wall1withkey"
    tools:context=".FireRoomActivity" 
   >

        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/zoomed_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/key_zoomed"
    android:visibility="gone"        />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/key"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="150dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="144dp"
                    android:onClick="zoomImage"
                     />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my activity:

```
int wall;
RelativeLayout parentLayout;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.water_room_view_flipper);
        wall=1;
        rl = (CustomView) findViewById(R.id.customView); 
        vf = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.water_room_flipper);

    }
public void zoomImage(View view)
    {
        parentLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.first);

         if(view.getId()==R.id.key){ 
            zoomedImage= (ImageView)parentLayout.findViewById(R.id.zoomed_image);
            ((BitmapDrawable)parentLayout.getBackground()).getBitmap().recycle();
            //set Alpha
            Drawable wall1withoutkey = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.wall1withoutkey);
            wall1withoutkey.setAlpha(100);
            parentLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(wall1withoutkey);    
            parentLayout.findViewById(R.id.key).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
                   zoomedImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         zoomedImage.setClickable(true);
         zoomedImage.setOnClickListener(this);}
}
```

Comment: Well could be a lot of reasons, you need to show some of your code so we can try to find where the error is....

Comment: I've added some code. The reason I didn't it before is the behaviour is not constant, most of the time it works as expected. But I want to be sure that it works all the time.

Comment: well maybe... in this line when you get you Relative layout  parentLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.first);  but the id of the relative layout is  android:id="@+id/wall1Layout"

Comment: I still see the layout though: its background image, the button. In the ViewFlipper xml I indicated it as first.